# Accessing a password protected video on DailyMotion

Tags: php, dailymotion-api

I am trying to build a PHP app to access & read my own movies on DailyMotion.
A movie on this DM site can have 3 different statuses : public, private, or password protected.

The movies I want to access belong to the latter categorie.
However, I did not find any help about how to provide the required "movie password" (NOT the owner pwd) on the API call issued when accessing it.
Any indication ?

Comment: Did you check the API website? https://developer.dailymotion.com/api#authentication

Comment: Please, see below.

Answer (score 2):

A quick read of the [DailyMotion API documentation](https://developer.dailymotion.com/api/#authentication) reveals that is uses OAuth 2.0 for authentication.

It also specifies that the apps are normally restricted to public content only, with the following note

> For accessing and/or manipulating protected resources (such as private user data), the client application (your application) needs to be granted permission to do so.

I recommend following the link above, for more information on how to gain this access.

Comment: Thanks. However, I need more info. I assume that to access a "pwd protected movie" as I explained in the original post, I must follow the explanations at " https://developer.dailymotion.com/tools/sdks#sdk-php-grant-password ". Right ?

Comment: If the above is right, is the "password" mentioned in the code example of this section the one which is precisely attached to the movie, please ?

Comment: It talks about logging in a user, using his or her credentials. I'd recommend reading the documentation a bit closer, testing the examples it gives. It should become apparent how it works then.